# Get cover art from mp3 files through PHP and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3

So I'm building a podcast website, I'd like to be able to upload songs and have the cover art appear next to the play button. I have jPlayer setup and the music part is all done, but how can I use - preferably PHP, but if not, javascript or jQuery - to grab the cover art that's embedded with the mp3 file and show it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a complete answer (no time right now, somebody else, feel free to do it), but http://getid3.org seems to be able to do this. See this forum discussion: http://www.getid3.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1062

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a Web-Services, http://www.lastfm.fr/api LastFm has a free to use webservice api, where get your information including covers, lastFm was just a quick google, there are many more.

Comment: @Pekka where do I find the referenced getid3.php?

Comment: @BjarkeCK actually, since these are podcasts, they won't be any real album art, just stuff I throw together and add to the mp3 file.

Comment: @JacksonGariety Here http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/1.9.3/

Comment: @Pekka thanks man! Shoulda looked a bit closer I guess. ;)

Comment: @Pekka I tried the php from the forum, it breaks. No error, something's just wrong.

Comment: Simply adding the library to my page breaks it -___-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Album art is a data frame identified as “Attached picture” due ID3v2 specification, and getID3() now is only one way to write all possible data frames in ID3v2 with pure PHP.

Look at this source: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/write.id3v2.phps

Search for this text in the source:

```
// 4.14  APIC Attached picture
```

there's a piece of code responsible for writing album art.

Another way, that seems to be not as slow as pure PHP, is to use some external application, that will be launched by PHP script. If your service designed to work under a high load, binary compiled tool will be a better solution.

**A better (faster) way to do this would be through an external application and 
the PHP exec() function to fun a command. I would recommend [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/).**

Comment: getID3 seems to be a suitable library, but the referenced example is all about *writing* ID3 tags, not *extracting*.